# Can a Villager vote himself?

Tags: werewolf

Some roles, like the angel or the village idiot, want to be voted themselves.

Is it valid to any villager to vote for himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No version of werewolf I have found forbids a player from voting for him/herself during the day.

---

### The Werewolves of Miller's Hollow

> The players, after much debating and arguing, must select one player that they want to eliminate when they vote.

---

### Stellar Factory Werewolf (playwerewolf.co)

> Daytime is very simple; all the living players gather in the village and decide who to kill. As soon as a majority of players vote for a particular player to kill, the moderator says "Ok, you're dead."

---

### Ultimate Werewolf

> Each day, the players discuss who among them is a werewolf, and vote out a player.

Comment: Actually, I was reffering to The Werewolves of Miller's Hollow and 3rd Extension: Characters

Comment: @Malkev I have edited the answer to cover 3 different versions of Werewolf, Miller's Hollow included